# How to access xmlns key, val in xml string

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml

Assuming the following XML is loaded into `data` (and only this data):

```
<stream:stream to='host.com' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' version='1.0'>
```

I would assume the following code could do the job:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
from io import StringIO

parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)

e = ET.parse(StringIO(data), parser)
root = e.getroot()

for key, val in root.items():
    print(key, val)
```

The output however is just:

```
to host.com
version 1.0
```

How do I access `xmlns='jabber:client'` and more importantly why isn't this a part of the result?

I've never liked XML and the whole thing with external namespace definitions is not to my liking so I've avoided it quite a bit, maybe I'm missing some fundamentals here?

Comment: The [xmlns](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) is a special attribute part of the XML markup rules and is not quite treated the same as a regular attribute. Aside - I've always liked XML. What else data structure is open-ended (any tree nesting) left to only the designer? Plus equipped with XSLT to restructure, XPath to parse content -a truly versatile/dynamic data type.

Comment: @Parfait Well you do have dictionaries (JSON) for one, it's less hassle and it does present a petter parsing structure than the XML raw data. But I guess it's a matter of taste and logic. And as you sad, `xmln` is a **special** deviant in the protocol that is thus treated different in the parsers which makes no sense to me. Data is data, it should all be picked up and the filtering should be optional and up to the developer.
Hence why I'm trying to convert the XML data into JSON so that all the data is accessible in the same manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the namespaces for a node by looking at the `.nsmap` property of `root`.

Comment: It works, but `xmlns=...` becomes `None : ....` for some reason. But I'll take it!

Comment: Yeah, I agree that's kind of weird. Not sure why they did it like that.